# Authenticate then retry with interceptor & ngrx store events

Tags: angular, ngrx, interceptor

I have the following code in an interceptor:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): any {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(async error => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error.status === 302 || error.status === 401 || error.status === 403)) {
          this.store.dispatch(new Authenticate());
          try {
            await firstValueFrom(this.store.pipe(
              select(selectAuthCallState),
              filter(state => state === ProcessState.COMPLETED),
              take(1)
            ));
          } catch (err) {
            return throwError(async () => new Error(error.message));
          }
        }
        return next.handle(request);
      })
    );
  }
```

1. When a HTTP request is getting a 401 error (for instance), it gets into the `catchError` block as expected.
2. `this.store.dispatch(new Authenticate());` is dispatching an authentication event, which works as expected.
3. Then, in order to detect the authentication completion, I'm awaiting the action to finish (by `await`ing the selector update) - works perfectly.
4. **I'm then trying to recall the original request (which was rejected by the lack of authentication), and nothing happens.**

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with. Should be switched to `retry` instead of deprecated `retryWhen`.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): any {
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  retryWhen(errors => {
    let count = 0;
    return errors.pipe(
      takeWhile(error =>
        (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) && ++count <= this.RETRY_COUNT)
      ),
      concatMap(async (error) => {
        this.store.dispatch(new Authenticate());
        await firstValueFrom(this.store.pipe(
          select(selectAuthCallState),
          filter(state => state === ProcessState.COMPLETED),
          take(1)));
        return of(error);
      })
    );
  })
);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I notice some bugs, Im not should that fixing them would fix your app

- lack of async before interceptor
- this rxjs's pipe doesn't have any retryWhen or retry (check [this](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/retry-failed-http-requests-in-angular-f5959d486294) tutorial)